# How do I draw this graph?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Given conditions are :
Note: $[x]$=Greatest Integer Function, $\{x\}$: Fractional part of $x$, $|x|$: Absolute value of $x$

For all $x \in [-3.5,3.5]$,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} |[x]| & \text{if } 0 \leq \{x\} <0.5, \\|x| & \text{if }0.5 \leq\{x\}<1. \end{cases} $$

Then find the sum of number of points where $f(x)$ is non-diffrentiable and number of  points where $f(x)$ is non continuous.

All I did was to try  and plot the graph. But for $x \in [-3.5,0] $ , I'm Having trouble. My current answer comes out to be $21$ . Can someone confirm?

Is there any other alternative other than graph plotting?

Comment: What's your definition of [x]? Specifically, is [-0.3]=-1 or [-0.3]=0?

Comment: @Alex [-0.3]=-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a WolframAlpha command for drawing this graph:

```
plot abs(x)*UnitStep(x-floor(x)-0.5)+abs(floor(x))*UnitStep(floor(x)+0.5-x)  from -3.5 to 3.5
```

I counted three discontinuities at negative $x$, namely:
$$
x = -2.5, -1.5, -0.5
$$
and four more discontinuities at positive $x$, they are
$$
x = 0.5, \ 1.5, \ 2.5, \ 3.5
$$
So overall $f(x)$ has $7$ discontinuities when $x\in[-3.5,3.5]$.

One important observation is that $f(x)=|x|$ when $\{x\}=0.5$; therefore we do not have a discontinuity at $x=-3.5$ but we do have a discontinuity at $x=3.5$.

Specifically, $x=3.5$ is a discontinuity because
$$
\lim_{x\to3.5^-}f(x)=3 \quad\mbox{ while }\quad f(3.5)=|3.5|=3.5.
$$
In addition to the discontinuities, $f(x)$ is not differentiable at the following points:
$$
x = -3.5, -3, -2, -1, \ 0, \ 1, \ 2, \ 3 \qquad\mbox{ (the slope of $f(x)$ changes at these $x$). }
$$
Therefore, overall $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $15$ points in $[-3.5,3.5]$. (A function defined on a segment is not differentiable at the segment endpoints because either the left or right limit does not exist at the endpoints.)

Comment: How is 3.5 a discontinuity?

Comment: I added explanation of x=3.5 in the answer itself.

Comment: So equal number of non-diffrentiables then? + 3 points in $R_{+}$ domain?

Comment: Plus zero; the slope of $f(x)$ changes at $x=0$ too.

Comment: Corrected the answer part for negative $x$; also $f(x)$ is not differentiable at endpoints of a closed interval (by most definitions).

Answer (score 1):

It should be clear that the only problems can come at integers and half integers.  There are only $15$ of those in the interval, so $21$ cannot be correct.  Just take the limit as you approach each of those from above and below.  For example near $x=+1.5$, when you are above $1.5$ you are in the second line of the function and $f(x)=x$.  As you approach from below you are in the first line, the floor is active, and $f(x)=1$.  There is a discontinuity because the two limits do not agree.  You could see what $f(1.5)$ is so you would know where to plot that on a graph, but it is not important.  You do need the value at the endpoints because it might disagree with the limit from the only side you have.